# Pandas group and sort dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
A   B
b   d
b   d
b   d
b   e
a   f
a   f
c   g
c   h
```

With the code

```
tables_df=df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index=False)['count'].sum().sort_values(by='count', ascending=False)
```

I can group and sort as

```
A   B   count
b   d   3
a   f   2
b   e   1
c   g   1
c   h   1
```

However I wish to group it and sort in descending order based on the count of column A only:

```
A   B   count
b   d   3
b   e   1
a   f   2
c   g   1
c   h   1
```

How can I do this?

To further clarify, the values should be sorted in descending order based on the count of column A only, however it should group values based on both columns. (In this case since b has the highest overall count it should be on top of the list and a has the second highest count and hence should be below b, even though b-e has a lower count than a-f it should be above a-f since b has a higher overall count).

Comment: It seems like ` df.groupby(['A', 'B']).A.count().reset_index(name='count')` would work, would it not?

Comment: @Zero The problem is sorting not grouping

Comment: @Zero It doesn't work, I want the df sorted based on column A only but grouped based on both column A and B

Comment: @COLDSPEED It doesn't sort as per the requirement

Comment: Then just do `df.groupby(['A', 'B']).A.count().reset_index(name='count').sort_values(['A', 'count'], ascending=[True, False])`?